# VBA Compile Error: Can't Assign to Read-Only Property Returning Array from Custom Class Get Property

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, return-type, class-properties

I'm having an issue with the *Get* property from a custom class in VBA (Excel 2010). If an index argument is not given, then my Get property should return a reference (at least that's my impression) to the Class' array. If an index is given, it should return the value in the given index in the private array.

```
' Custom Class Properties
Private pMtbSheets() As String

'Get and Let Methods
Public Property Get MtbSheets(Optional index As Variant) As String()
    If IsMissing(index) Then
        ReDim MtbSheets(1 To UBound(pMtbSheets))
        MtbSheets = pMtbSheets()
    Else
        ReDim MtbSheets(1 To 1)
        MtbSheets(1) = pMtbSheets(index) '**Compiler error occures here**
    End If
End Property
```

Thanks for any help anyone is able to offer

Comment: Your function specification says the return value is a `String array`. You're getting the error because your Else condition is attempting to return a single string. To me anyway, this would be a confusing return from a function because I'd have to check the Type of the returned variable before using it. However, to solve your function as written, change the return value from `as String` to `as Variant`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a temporary array to avoid ambiguity between `MtbSheets(i)` being interpreted as a property/method/function call vs an array access:

```
ReDim temp(1 To 1) As String
temp(1) = pMtbSheets(index)
MtbSheets = temp
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks Alex. Additionally, I needed to use a temp array in the first part of the If statement.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: of course my answer won't work, you will need to use a temporary array as mentioned by Alex K. in his answer.

Just return the array like you do in your IsMissing() branch:

```
' Custom Class Properties
Private pMtbSheets() As String

'Get and Let Methods
Public Property Get MtbSheets(Optional index As Variant) As String()
    If IsMissing(index) Then
        ReDim MtbSheets(1 To UBound(pMtbSheets))
        MtbSheets = pMtbSheets()
    Else
        ReDim MtbSheets(1 To 1)
        MtbSheets = pMtbSheets(index)
    End If
End Property
```